# header and location.href won´t load another page and use root directory instead

Tags: javascript, php

I try to include some buttons on my php website that redirect to my github but instead of redirecting to my github they try to find the link in myd directory. So instead of getting github.com I get localhost/projects/index.php/github.com

Comment: Probably forgetting to include the protocol part of the url. Provide the relevant code. Without it we can only guess what is going wrong

Answer (score 0):

try `<a href="//github.com">GOOD LINK</a>` instead of `<a href="github.com">BAD LINK</a>`

Comment: I would recommend that you add some explanatory text to your answer, or you risk having it deleted as 'low quality' (even though it may be a correct answer)!

Answer (score 0):

For buttons you can apply the following html, you have to include the HTTPS protocol otherwise it will be interpreted as a local document.

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='https://github.com/'">Github</button>
```